# I have a Dataframe problem in Python, How to map two different data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I Have two data frame df1 and df2.

This is df1

```
      Name       Sector
0     Company1   3D
1     Company2   Accounting
2     Company3   Wireless
```

This is df2

```
      Name       Automotive&Sports Cleantech Entertainment Health Manufacturing Finance
0     3D                0             0          0           0        1           0
1     wireless          0             0          1           0        0           0
2     Accounting        0             0          0           0        0           1
```

Based on the values from a column in df1['sector'], I want to get the name of column which has value 1 for the rows in df2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have in `df2` is called a *one-hot encoding*, and one way to reverse that encoding is with `idxmax`. Let's add a column with that :

```
df2['result'] = df2.iloc[:, 1:].idxmax(1)
```

Now you just need to merge and do some cleanup:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2[['Name','result']], left_on='Sector', right_on='Name')
df = df.drop('Name_y', 1).rename(columns={'Name_x': 'Name'})
```

and you get the desired output:

```
In [102]: df
Out[102]: 
       Name      Sector         result
0  Company1          3D  Manufacturing
1  Company2  Accounting        Finance
2  Company3    Wireless  Entertainment
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code I  guess this what you are looking for,

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, df1.Sector == df2.Name, 'inner') \
    .drop(df2.Name)

for col_name in df3.columns:
    if (df3.filter(col(col_name) == 0).count() == df3.select(col(col_name)).count()):
        df3 = df3.drop(col_name)

df3.show()

+--------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------+
|    Name|    Sector|Entertainment|Manufacturing|Finance|
+--------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------+
|Company3|  Wireless|            1|            0|      0|
|Company2|Accounting|            0|            0|      1|
|Company1|        3D|            0|            1|      0|
+--------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------+
```